# Can I use the safe operator with square bracket property access in Angular template?

Tags: angular, angular9

In typescript, I can do "optional chaining" like so (as of 3.7.0):

```js
const cell = col.selector ? rowData[col.field]?.[col.selector] : rowData[col.field];
```

If I try to do something similar in my Angular template using the safe operator, it throws a compiler error as if I were misusing a ternary operator.

```html
<div>{{ col.selector ? rowData[col.field]?.[col.selector] : rowData[col.field] }}</div>
```

Error:

> Parser Error: Conditional expression col.selector ? rowData[col.field]?.[col.selector] : rowData[col.field] requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [{{ col.selector ? rowData[col.field]?.[col.selector] : rowData[col.field] }}]

Is there an other syntax I can use in my Angular template that gives a similar result as the typescript snippet? Last resort is to write a very simple helper function in the typescript that returns the "cell" value from the first snippet, but I'd prefer if I can keep this in the template.

Comment: how do you read  `rowData` & `col` in html ? pls provide the code snippet of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the prettier syntax, but this may works:

```
<div>{{ rowData[col.field] ? (col.selector ? rowData[col.field][col.selector] : rowData[col.field]) : null  }}</div>
```

So first check if `rowData[col.field]` is defined. If it is, procede with your snippet (which is wrapped on parentheses); since `rowData[col.field]` was already checked and it's supposed to be defined, there's no need to check it again with the *safe operator* so we can change `rowData[col.field]?.[col.selector]` to `rowData[col.field][col.selector]`.

If you want a cleaner syntax, as seems like you have an idea of how to reach this with a helper function, you can take that function to a pipe and pass as parameter the properties you want to access.

Comment: While I agree that it's not exactly the cleanest, it definitely works and answers the question as asked. I suppose I should choose between this and a helper function, though it'd be really nice if they considered adding this syntax in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

The amount you can do with a template expression is limited.

Angular documentation mentions that you are unable to use optional chaining operators in a template expression (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions)

> You can't use JavaScript expressions that have or promote side
> effects, including:
>
> Assignments (=, +=, -=, ...) Operators such as new, typeof,
> instanceof, etc. Chaining expressions with ; or , The increment and
> decrement operators ++ and -- Some of the ES2015+ operators Other
> notable differences from JavaScript syntax include:
>
> No support for the bitwise operators such as | and & New template
> expression operators, such as |, ?. and !

Comment: "Angular documentation mentions that you are unable to use optional chaining operators in a template expression" - I'm not sure I agree with you. It says you cannot chain expressions, but that's not the same as typescript's "optional chaining" (or "safe operator" as Angular calls it). Perhaps the wording of my question was misleading.